# How to open DbVisualizer connection (GUI) from commandline?

Tags: dbvisualizer

I wonder if it's possible to start the DbVisualizer GUI and open a db connection per command? Anyone knows if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. Please see

http://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG95/GUI+Command+Line+Arguments

Best Regards,
Hans (DbVis team)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the docs. Do I understand it correctly that specifiying a jdbc connection URL is not possible? I need to be independent from formerly created connections.

Comment: Yes, the connection must be set up using the GUI before you can use it with then command line. I will open a ticket for looking into if we can support just a URL for the simple cases where there isn't a lot of other setup required.

Comment: MKorsch: we've just released a beta of the upcoming 10.0 version. Among other news it supports running the command-line interface without first needing to define the database in the DbVisualizer tool. More info and download at http://www.dbvis.com/download/beta/